# Insert function not working [phpmyadmin, mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm trying to create SQL stored function in phpmyadmin to call it in PHP code when inserting into users. Everything looks fine but not working, I don't understand why.

I kinda tried in different ways but always end up not working. Hoping that someone will help.

So this is my table users in phpmyadmin

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `utilisateurs`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `utilisateurs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_sexe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_pays` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_typeUtilisateur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mot_de_passe` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `ref_typeUtilisateur` (`ref_typeUtilisateur`),
  KEY `ref_pays` (`ref_pays`),
  KEY `ref_sexe` (`ref_sexe`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this is my stored function in phpmyadmin.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `CreerUtilisateur`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CreerUtilisateur` (`EmailUser` VARCHAR(255), `ConfirmerEmailUser` VARCHAR(255), `MotDePasseUser` VARCHAR(255), `ConfirmerMDPUser` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1 MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    IF Email = "" THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez encoder votre email";
    END IF;
    IF ConfirmerEmail = "" THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez confirmer votre email";
    END IF;
    IF ConfirmerEmail != Email THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez encoder le meme email";
    END IF;
    IF MotDePasse = "" THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez encoder votre mot de passe";
    END IF;
    IF ConfirmerMDP = "" THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez confirmer votre mot de passe";
    END IF;
    IF ConfirmerMDP != MotDePasse THEN
        RETURN "Veuillez encoder le meme mot de passe";
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO utilisateurs
    SET 
    id = null,
    nom = null,
    prenom = null,
    ref_sexe = null,
    utilisateurs.email = EmailUser,
    tel = null,
    ref_pays = null,
    utilisateurs.ref_typeUtilisateur = 2,
    utilisateurs.mot_de_passe = CrypterMotDePasse(MotDePasseUser);
    RETURN (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
```

This is a registration form.

```
 Email - EmailConfirmation
 Password - PasswordConfirmation
```

And the insert should add a user with email/password (hashed) and by default `utilisateurs.ref_typeUtilisateur` is set to `User`.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: PHPmyadmin is a tool to display data. Mysql is the database you build your query on.

Comment: Doesn't work isn't much help. Does the `insert` work as expected if done directly (not in the stored function)? Have you verified that you are actually passing the correct values to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn't working.
Everything is fine except (Email, ConfirmerEmail, MotDePasse, ConfirmerMDP)

Correction:

```
Email => EmailUser
ConfirmerEmail => ConfirmerEmailUser,
MotDePasse => MotDePasseUser,
ConfirmerMDP => ConfirmerMDPUser
```

This is what happens when you're not focused.